# How to install Windows 10 without OEM partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, oem

When I install Windows from my usb drive.  It will automatically create a OEM partition, a EFI parition, a system reserved paririon and windows 10 OS partition.  AFAIK, if you use your own media driver to install windows 10, OEM partition is completely useless.

**Questions:**
1. Why windows 10 create OEM in the first place?
2. How can I install Windows 10 without OEM partition?

Comment: It doesn't create an OEM partition automatically. I've installed multiple times never saw that happening.

Comment: Sounds like a leftover oem partition, we need more information.

Answer (score 2):

Windows normally doesn't create an OEM partition at all.
If that happens in your case you either:

1. Have an existing OEM parition already, in which case Windows leaves it alone.
2. Have a non-standard install media that creates the partition.

So make sure the disk is really empty before you start the installation and use a standard W10 install medium.(You can download and write to USB official W10 setup media by using the Microsoft Media Creation software).

Comment: I downloaded ISO directly from microsoft official website. Before I install, I even used gpart to wipe all the partition tables and create a empty gpt table.  Then, I use  setup to install windows on one single unallocated disk.  Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: [The only partitions created by default are *System, MSR, Windows, and Recovery.*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions).  If you have an "OEM Partition" it means it already existed, and as Tonny indicated, the Windows Installer does not touch it.

Comment: That is the right way to do it and normally there shouldn't appear an OEM partition. However... There are some computers where the (UEFI-) Bios creates a small OEM diagnostic partition when it detects being started with an empty disk. (I've never seen it myself but I've heard of this with some HP models.) Also there are some computers (laptops) that have a small independent Linux based mini-OS that allows you to quickly check mail and some other basic things, without booting in the regular OS. Such systems may also create a small OEM partition all by themselves.

Comment: @Ramhound On my laptop, recovery partition is marked as OEM and it’s the first partition of the disk which I can’t simply delete and expand other partitions.  https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/delete-recovery-partition.html, it seems a vender issue?  My model is dell insprion 7380.

Comment: There isn't any reason you cannot delete the OEM partition.  You just can't do with Disk Mangement.  If it's the first partition deleting it is sort of useless unless you use a third-party tool to reorganized your partitions

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I can delete by cmd, the problem is ntfs can only extend a partition to the next one, which even if I delete OEM, I can’t make use of it.

Comment: Third party partition managers are not limited like that.